# How to have BroadcastService communicate with Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-broadcast

I'm trying to get push notification working in my Android app, using parse.com's [push notification service](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android). They implement a Broadcast receiver, which I am extending in my own class:

```
public class MyPushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        JSONObject data = getDataFromIntent(intent);

        [...]

        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I'm over-riding two methods:

- onPushReceive - this is called when a notification arrives
- onPushOpen - this is called when the user clicks on a notification in the notification area

There are three things I need to do:

1. When a notification arrives, I need to save it
2. When the user clicks on a notification, I need to open the app to an activity that displays the notifications I've saved
3. If a notification arrives while I have the app open to the display notifications activity, I need to update the UI to include the new activity.

The first part was easy. I'm just writing some JSON to a file.

The second I've had no trouble with.  I create an intent, and that opens my activity. It reads the JSON from the file, and Bob's your uncle.

I've not been able to find a clean way of handling the third part.

I think where I'm stuck is that I haven't a clear understanding of the lifecycle of Activities or BroadcastServices. I'm not creating either, in my app, they're declared in the manifest, and constructed whenever.

Does the Android framework create one of each, as it processes the manifest?  Is it possible for an activity to find the instance of the BroadcastReceiver? If I could, it'd be easy enough for me to wire up a callback between them.

Or do I need to define my own BroadcastService, that the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver would use to publish events, and that the activity would consume?  The examples I've seen on doing that seem excessively complicated for what should be a fairly simple thing.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for asking non relevant question. I'm new to parse, is it every activity have to use this line of code "trackAppOpenedInBackground" or only start up page for tracking purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion on using a static variable got me thinking, and I think I've found a workable solution.

There may be multiple instances of an Activity, but only one can be active at any time.

I spent some time playing around with setting various flags on the Intent I'd pass to startActivity(), and didn't like any of the behaviors I'd see.  (Some combinations would crash, some would create multiple entries in the stack so that the back button returned you to an older instance of the activity, all of them created visual effects as the old activity was replaced by the new.)

So, why not create a static field that points to the currently active Activity?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ReceiveNotifications
{
    public static ReceiveNotifications notificationReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        NotificationsActivity.notificationReceiver = this;

        updateMessages();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        NotificationsActivity.notificationReceiver = null;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationReceived()
    {
        updateMessages();
    }

    private void updateMessages()
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Whenever an instance of MyActivity is active, the static variable notificationReceiver will point to it. Of course, I'm using an interface to control how much of MyActivity is visible through that variable:

```
public interface ReceiveNotifications
{
    void notificationReceived();
}
```

Then, when we receive a notification, if notificationReceiver is not null, we call notificationReceived():

```
public class MyPushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        JSONObject data = getDataFromIntent(intent);

        [...]

        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    if (MyActivity.notificationReceiver != null)
        MyActivity.notificationReceiver.notificationReceived();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onNewIntent()` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))) method of the Activity to send the new info about something happened and then display some prompt.

Comment: I want the BroadcastReceiver to update the Activity only if the Activity is active. I don't want to bring the Activity forward, if it isn't, already.

Comment: In that case you can store the activity context in some static variable. When you receive a new notification check for this static variable if not null use that to display prompt to user.